# How do I get jquery animation to loop

Tags: jquery, parallax

I basically have a simple animation happening on a parallax website. After the first group of images animates (sweeps in then out via moving margins), I use TimeOut to remove it and then queue in the second group of images. Works fine, I just need it to loop.

```
$('#slide5').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {

        function runIt() {

            $('.img-promo').stop().animate({marginLeft: '30%'},{duration:750})

            $('.img-tour').stop().animate({marginLeft: '30%'},{duration:750})
            $('.img-distro').stop().animate({marginLeft: '30%'},{duration:750})

            $('.img-promo').delay(1800).stop().animate({marginLeft: '-40%'},{duration:750})

            $('.img-tour').delay(1800).stop().animate({marginLeft: '-40%'},{duration:750})
            $('.img-distro').delay(1800).stop().animate({marginLeft: '-40%'},{duration:750})

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".img-promo").hide();
                $(".img-tour").hide();

                $(".img-distro").hide();

            }, 3900);

            $('.img-album').delay(3800).stop().animate({marginLeft: '30%'},{duration:750})

            $('.img-mastering').delay(3800).stop().animate({marginLeft: '30%'},{duration:750})
            $('.img-event').delay(3800).stop().animate({marginLeft: '30%'},{duration:750})

            $('.img-album').delay(1800).stop().animate({marginLeft: '-40%'},{duration:750})

            $('.img-mastering').delay(1800).stop().animate({marginLeft: '-40%'},{duration:750})
            $('.img-event').delay(1800).stop().animate({marginLeft: '-40%'},{duration:750})
        }
        runIt();
    }
    else {
        $('.img-promo').animate({marginLeft: '-90%'},{duration:750})
        $('.img-tour').animate({marginLeft: '120%'},{duration:750})

        $('.img-distro').animate({marginLeft: '-90%'},{duration:750})
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ sample ?

Comment: Why do you remove it? Why not just hide it? You making it more difficult to loop your animation if you remove your elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MELPQ/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callback function of each animation to load next animation then at the end you move to the beginning

Here is a sample from jQuery 
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```